# Copy if part of the text cell found excel VBA

Tags: string, excel, text, find, vba

I am having a hard time to write that VBA...

Attached picture should help to understand what I need to do

Problem:

a) If text "FAA" is found in Sheet1 Column B then copy cell C in the same row to Sheet2 Column A.

[image]

then,

b) Delete those cells in row B and C of Sheet1.

Comment: Do you really want to delete the column **B** and column **C** cells or just clear their contents ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For each cel in .Range(.Range("B1"),.Range("B1").End(xlDown))

       If cel.Value Like "*FAA*" Then 
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cel.Offset(,1).Value
          cel.Resize(1,2).ClearContents

       End If

    Next

   'if you wish to remove the rows entirely use this code, if not comment out   
   .Range(.Range("B1"),.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(,1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End With
```

Comment: I'd rather like to have the column B and column C cells deleted, Column A will stay untouched...

Comment: then just comment out or delete the last line in the code before the `End With` @FotoDJ

Comment: how that offset (,1) in last line work, I can not figure that out?

Comment: `cel.Offset(,1).Value`?

Comment: .Range(.Range("B1"),.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(,1)). - that part

Comment: Is it the way you selected range from Cell B1 to the last Cell in Column B1, offsetted one column to the right , which is C1, am I correct? @ Scott Holtzman

Comment: @FotoDJ - almost correct. It's `Range("B1")` all the way down to the last row in column A, offset by 1 column, so the same row in column B. I used an `End(xlDown)` on column A to get the last row because all the data is still in tact in that column.